# Translate SQL Query into LINQ Query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

can someone help me to translate this SQL query into LINQ

```
select * from server where server.GruppenName like ( select Gruppen.Name from Gruppen where Id = 1 )
```

I have tried following

```
db.Server.Where(b => b.GruppenName == db.Gruppen.First(c => c.Id == 1).Name);
```

but no luck.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.Server
    .Where
    (
        x=>
            db.Gruppen
            .Where(g=>g.Id == 1)
            .Select(g=>g.Name)
            .Contains(x.GruppenName)
    );
```

Comment: @maddin I think this translates into a  `in` rather than a `like`

Comment: @Aducci Indeed, but the way OPs sql statement is written `IN` is implied.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos - You are correct, my answer is actually not the same as his original sql query, mine would be `like %...%`

Answer (score 1):

**Method Syntax**

```
db.Server.Where(s => db.Gruppen.Where(g => g.Id == 1)
                               .Where(g => g.Name.Contains(s.GruppenName))
                               .Any());
```

**Query Syntax**

```
var query = from s in db.Server
            where (from g in db.Gruppen
                   where g.Id == 1
                   where g.Name.Contains(s.GruppenName)
                   select s).Any()
            select s;
```